# Should You Have a Separate Boot Partition When You Are Dual Booting Linux and Windows?

Tags: boot, partition, dual-boot

When you are installing a modern Linux distribution, you generally don't need to have a separate `/boot`; however, there *do* seem to be special circumstances/scenarios that necessitate having a separate `/boot`  partition. I am wondering if dual booting Linux and Windows is one of those circumstances. If so, I would love an explanation as to why this is.

Answer (score 2):

On modern UEFI systems, the EFI System Partition (ESP for short; the partition where the firmware loads the bootloader from) may be mounted at `/boot/efi` or `/boot`, depending on distribution. Some distributions leave the ESP completely unmounted for normal use, *but will still need to know where it is* in order to update the bootloader or its configuration when needed.

The ESP may be shared with the Windows bootloader (or indeed with the bootloaders of any UEFI specification compliant OS) if it has enough space, or if you have Linux and Windows on separate disks, you can have a dedicated ESP for each disk/OS. Having a dedicated ESP for each disk will make things easier if you someday wish to move one disk or the other to another computer without reinstalling the OS: each disk will be bootable on its own without depending on the presence of the other disk.

The ESP must use a filesystem type that is supported by the firmware: support of FAT32 is guaranteed by the UEFI specification, but hardware vendors may opt to support other filesystems too. Native Linux filesystems are unlikely to be supported, so you can't just designate your root partition as an ESP.

This is different from the use of the `/boot` partition on legacy BIOS systems.

On BIOS-based systems of late 1990s to about 2004 or so, the sizes of the disks grew faster than the specifications of BIOS extensions could keep up with. In 2003, the now-standard LBA48 access method was specified, and it supports disk sizes up to the 128 petabyte range.

On systems with an old BIOS that cannot access the full size of the disk using BIOS functions, it is important to make sure the bootloader, the kernel and the initramfs file stay near the beginning of the disk, within the range of disk space the BIOS *can* access. Having them all in a separate `/boot` partition that is appropriately located and sized is one sure way to achieve that. If you don't have such a limitation, then you won't need a `/boot` partition in the classic sense.

Modern versions of GRUB now include direct ATA and AHCI support, which can also be used to work around these BIOS limitations by GRUB driving the disk controller hardware directly, bypassing the BIOS; however, depending on the distribution used, such support might not be enabled by default, as it is much less well-tested than the corresponding BIOS-based code, and the documentation of these features is very sparse.